# how to delete account a se account specifically chemse?

Tags: discussion

I searched my profile but didn't found any delete buttons.
 Can anyone help me delete my account?
I have been trying to delete it for some time.I googled and and found a contact form which does not accept my profile link which is a must.

Comment: Have you checked http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account? If you use the [contact form](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/contact#) then your profile link should be included automatically. It should be `http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/27255/sheogorath`

Comment: @Martin-マーチンI kicked off the process, and the OP has the ability to change their mind over the next 24 hours.

Comment: @jonsca I just saw this (didn't ping), thanks for taking the lead on that one :D And obviously the OP did not change her/his mind...

Answer (score 5):

Just dropping this here so we'd have something to close as a dupe of next time this question appears.

The [Help Center](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account) explains the process of account deletion elaborately:

> If your account has never voted or posted more than once:
>
> <sub>You should see a delete option on your user profile by clicking the *Edit Profile & Settings* link on [most sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/):</sub>
>
> [image]
>
> [$\ldots$]
>   If you have voted or posted, please contact the Stack Exchange Team:
>
> <sub>Visit the [contact form](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/contact) and select 'I need to delete my user profile.' After you contact us, the team will reach out with further instructions.</sub>